# Concatenating numbers that have leading zeros

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, concatenation

I'm trying to combine/concatenate numbers in different columns into one long number. Some of the numbers have leading zeros because of custom formats applied to the cells. When I concatenate them together, the zeros are removed. Does someone know how the formula should look so that the leading zeros aren't removed?

Example:
A1 = 08,
B1 = 7,
C1 = 0,
D1 = 17,
E1 = 00,
F1 = 01,
G1 = Concentrated number from A1 to F1

The resulting number should be `0870170001` however the following number appears `8701701`.

I'm using Excel 2010, and this is the formula I've tried: `=CONCATENATE(A1;B1;C1;D1;E1;F1)`.

Comment: *Numbers* can't have leading zeroes because "3" and "03" are two different *representations* of the same *number*. Confusing numbers with number representations will cause you no end of problems using computers and especially programming them.

Answer (score 2):

You *may* not need the ; but instead, use a comma to show each is a separate string value (this may depend on localization settings - Thanks Bob).

```
=CONCATENATE(A1,B1,C1,D1,E1,F1)
```

However, you will need to make sure that the cells with the numbers in are formatted to text by highlighting the row and in the Home ribbon, under Number tab, in the drop down list select 'Text'.

[image]

Comment: I think Excel uses semicolons rather than commas to separate parameters in some localisations... (IIRC it's the ones that use commas to indicate the decimal point [radix point])

Comment: Thanks @Bob, I didn't realize that. Updating answer accordingly (although cautiously)

Comment: Is there a way to combine columns that are formatted as "custom" and not as "text"?

Comment: You can concatenate most formatted cells (it doesn't do well with decimal places though unless it's a string). The issue is whether the cell displays the data as you want.

Comment: If the user's data is in a custom format, changing the format of the cell to Text will change how the data is displayed and change what is passed to the concatenation formula. For this reason, changing the format is not a solution.

Comment: @Helpneeded - you never stated this in your OP - and since other posters have commented based upon your comments in this post it may be confusing for future visitors - can you please edit your OP (original post) to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

I see from your comment that your cells most likely have custom formats, and the displayed value in these cells is likely different from the entered value (e.g. "8" is shown as "08"). In this case, you can concatenate each value wrapped in a `TEXT` function with the specified format of the cell.  For example, if `A1` has custom format "00", you would use `TEXT(A1,"00")` as the term for `A1` in your concatenation formula.  For the full formula, you may have something like this:

```
=TEXT(A1,"00")&TEXT(B1,"@")&TEXT(C1,"0")&...
```

Of course, this is tedious as it requires you to manually recreate the format of each cell. If you're going to be using this a lot with lots of varied formats, I would say this is a perfect opportunity to use a VBA function to do the heavy lifting.  You can paste the following code into a module in the VBA Editor (opened by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>).

```
Public Function CONCATwFORMATS(rng1 As Range) As String
Dim tmpstr As String, tmpFormat As String
Dim c As Range

For Each c In rng1
    tmpFormat = c.NumberFormat
    If tmpFormat = "General" Then
        tmpstr = tmpstr & c.Value
    Else
        tmpstr = tmpstr & Format(c.Value, tmpFormat)
    End If
Next c
CONCATwFORMATS = tmpstr
End Function
```

Then, you can use the following formula in `G1`.

```
=CONCATwFORMATS(A1:F1)
```

This is just a quick attempt at this code, so note two requirements of the function:

1. It only takes a contiguous range as an argument.
2. It concatenates the values in order from left to right (and top to bottom).

The code can be tweaked to remove these restrictions, but for what you want, it sounds like this will work fine.